# CxClasses unit is automatically gets added in Uses section

Tags: delphi, devexpress

When i trying to build the project CxClasses unit is automatically gets added in Uses section. Due to which i am getting error while running the exe.

I dont want to include CxClasses in uses. How should i avoid this thing??

Thanks for help..

Regards,
Naren

Comment: Are you sure it gets added when *building*? I'd think it gets added when you save your unit after trying to remove it. If so then one of the components on the associated form thinks that it needs cxClasses - sometimes erroneously so.

Comment: cxClasses is a devexpress unit. Where is it getting added? What triggers it to get added? What is the error you get when running the exe? What devexpress components are you using? Are you using static linking or runtime packages? Please tell us some details and then we can help.

Comment: Yes while trying to build project its get added or when we close any pas file then its get added at last in uses section. Its getting added in every unit which i open and close.Error --> "Exception reading dxBM.ImageOptions.Images property does not exist ". I am using delphi 5 and developer express build version is 27.  using the static version. thanks for the help and quick reply -Naren

Comment: @Naren What did devexpress say when you contacted them?

Comment: It's added when saving. Are you sure you/someone hasn't messed with the dfm-file as text

Comment: @david- I have not contacted to DevExpress yet.

Comment: its getting add whenever i open that pass file and close. it asks me Save the file or not?? still if i clicked on "No" and try to compile the projects its gets added automatically.. :( I am unable to find which component needs that file.. :( plz help.. thanks for response.. --- Naren

Answer (score 2):

There is a component on your form/frame/datamodule which requires the unit. When the IDE designer saves the form/frame/datamodule it also makes sure the required unit is included in the uses clause. Delete the component(s) and the problem should not appear again.

Comment: how to find out which component is using that file?? -- Naren

Comment: The component or a class which the component exposes as a published property will be in the unit. Open the unit and see what classes it contains in its interface section, then check which of them are placed on your form.

Answer (score 1):

You have a component on your form that comes from or uses that unit. The IDE adds it automatically so that your code will compile.

You'll need to investigate your run-time error from a different angle. It's unlikely to be caused *solely* by including that unit.

Comment: What was it you once said to me about answering when the question isn't clear?   ;-)

Comment: @David: Always a tough decision: Ask for clarification in a comment (like I did :-P)) or be the first to answer.